# Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation, where $n\ge2$. For $k\le n$, let $E=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $F=\{Tv_1,Tv_2,\dots,Tv_k\}$, then which of the following is true.

$A.$ If $E$ is linearly independent, then $F$ is linearly independent

$B.$ If $F$ is linearly independent, then $E$ is linearly independent.

$C.$ If $E$ is linearly independent, then $F$ is linearly dependent

$D.$ If $F$ is linearly independent, then $E$ is linearly dependent.

Please help me out with this problem. And if some theorem is responsible for it's solution please mention that.

Answer (score 4):

A is not true, consider $T = 0$, the zero transformation.

B is true, for suppose there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_k v_k = 0.$$
Applying $T$ on both sides of the above equation and use the linearity of $T$ gives that
$$a_1 Tv_1 + \cdots + a_k Tv_k = 0.$$
Since $F$ is linearly independent, we must have $a_1 = \cdots = a_k = 0$, therefore, $E$ is linearly independent.

C is not true, consider $T = I$, the identity transformation.

D is not true, for $B$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ False: take the $0_n$ matrix.

$B$ True: suppose $v_k = \sum a_iv_i$, then $Tv_k =\sum a_iTv_i$, absurd.

$C$ False: take the $I_n$ matrix.

$D$ False: take the $I_n$ matrix.

Write down your efforts next time please!